# Move Files in Directory to Dated Directory C# - Getting convert error

Tags: c#

I am trying to automate a file move to dated folders but I am getting a

> Suppression State Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

The code is as follows:

```
IEnumerable<string> files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"PICS_CAM1\");
//string files = @"PICS_CAM1\";

string Todaysdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
string newPath = Path.Combine(@"PICS_CAM1\", Todaysdate);

if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);

File.Move(files, Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(newPath)));  <--error on this line    
//File.Move(dir, newPath);
```

As stated the error I am getting is on the word files in the file.move line: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string

Comment: That error is pretty explanatory as to why you are getting it..

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)? Clearly it doesn't accept an `IEnumerable<string>` as the first argument, but a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `Files` is `IEnumerable<string>` and `File.Move` accepted type is `string`.

To fix it:

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
   File.Move(file, Path.Combine(newPath, Path.GetFileName(newPath)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Karolis, that fixed the error but it now moves the file and renames it the name of the dated directory.  I had a \PICS_CAM1\test.text and it move it to \18-MAY-2017\18-MAY-2017.  with no extension.  I just want to move to \18-MAY-2017\test.txt  Ideas?  I tried removing the \ on the files name.

Comment: @BradJarrett You can figure that out yourself by clearly thinking through your naming logic.

Comment: @BradJarrett That is another question. Please do your investigation around the subject. If you got additional problems a long the way you are more than free to post it on SO.

Comment: I don't think this is another question.  I am trying to move files and the solution actually renamed them.  I am new to c# so don't understand why the rename?  But I can repost if I must.

Comment: @BradJarrett... you're being lazy and not wanting to try anything yourself is what i see.. You could easily just debug your solution and figure it out yourself

Comment: austin, not true.. I am new to c# and have been working on this for 4 hours trying to debug before i posted.  Still learning the language.

Comment: Accepted Karolis answer..thank you for your help... I will figure out the naming issue.

Comment: and I just figured it out...should be Path.GetFileName(file) not Path.GetFileName(newPath)

Comment: @Bard Jarret Well you see, wasn't so hard. :)

Comment: Sometimes after looking at it over and over again, you step on your own thinking :)